# ActiveStorage Running on AWS Lambda Without Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, rails-activestorage

We are currently trying to extract a cron task into a AWS lambda function. The goal is to trigger the lambda function with cloudwatch events (every 15 minutes for example) - we'd like to run this on lambda as it only runs every few minutes and we would like to prevent the webserver from crashing if the cron task runs into issues.

The main issue seems to be getting ActiveStorage configured without booting a full Rails application. I found this in the Active Storage Docs:

```rb
# If you are using Active Storage outside of a Ruby on Rails application, you can configure the service to use like this:
ActiveStorage::Blob.service = ActiveStorage::Service.configure(
  :Disk,
  root: Pathname("/foo/bar/storage")
)
```

When our lambda function tries to initialize ActiveStorage we get a uninitialized constant ActiveStorage::Blob. I've locally included and required 'active_storage' and 'active_record' in our initializer.

Curious if anyone has run into any solutions for running a lambda function that required an ActiveStorage configuration.